# Java: Jersey: How to handle multiple query parameters

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have a rest API

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list
```

The implementation for the same is

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getTodos(){
  return todoService.getTodos();
}
```

I need to write the implementation for the below API's

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status=CRITICAL

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status=MAJOR

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed&todo.title={title}

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed&todo.title={title}&todo.startDate={startDate}
```

Is it possible for a single path annotation to handle all the implementations?

My concern is **todo.completion.status=completed** is defaulted in the query itself.

I have even looked at the below solution it does not work for me for the above mentioned reason.

[Java REST API Query annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100241/java-rest-api-query-annotation)

**Update**

I have avoided using @QueryParam as I have good number of arguments to be handled and the list is likely to grow. The method signature will only grow in future and it will affect readability of the code.

Hence, I have chosen to use UriInfo.

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getTodos(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
  MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The rest Query that I am building writes a query to collect information from other services. The issue with this approach is we can any parameters, How do I restrict the user to use only of the above parameters?

Comment: `@QueryParam` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, I have avoided using "@QueryParam" as I have good number of arguments to be handled and the list is likely to grow.  As an alternative approach, I have decided to use UriInfo. I have updated the implementation on the question.  But the issue that I am facing is. How to I restrict the user to use only of the above mentioned parameters?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, Or is there a better way to handle it?